# How to connect a concrete 2D array to a previously defined pointer to a pointer in a header file?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to implement a checkers game.
I have to use a given header file which contains some #defines and statements.
one of them is:

```
typedef char** board_t;
```

I understand that this is a pointer to a pointer to a char i.e that:

```
 **board_t = board_t[0][0]
```

In the checkers.c file I am implementing some methods with a board 2d array input.

In some of them I'm interested in changing the board so I want to insert it using a pointer.

considering the header typedef, is it ok to define the board this way:

```
char board_t [BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
```

and then to use it in a method :

```
void init_board(board_t){...}
```

in this writing am I really passing on a pointer to the previously defined 2d array?

if so, how do I approach `board[i][j]`  using this pointer in the method?

Answer (score 0):

Note that pointers and arrays are not equivalent in all aspects. There are subtle differences which should be elaborated in a good C book or tutorial (otherwise it is not good).

`board_t = board_t[0][0]`; that is wrong. You assign an integer (`char`) to a pointer. **Hint:** always enable most warnings. For gcc, at least `-Wall` ist strongly recommended, adding `-Wextra` is good advice.

If you just want a 2D array, it is still `char *board_t`. You do not have to add one `*` per dimension (that would be for an array of pointer to array).

**Notes:**

- A `_t` suffix should be reserved for implementation defined types. Your name might collide with such a type for a later version of the language. For custom types, CamelCase is commonly used (no specific prefix/suffix).
- Using the same name for a type name and a variable is not allowed (it will generate an error).

For conversion of pointers, you should read the standard, expecially [6.3.2.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) and [6.7.6.3p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7) are of interest here.

Briefly, if you have a formal function argument of array type, that will implicitly converted to a pointer to that same type. If you apply the array operator on a pointer, that will have the same semantics as for an array.

Comment: "board_t <=> &board_t[0][0]" No, `board_t` implicitly converts to `&board_t[0]`

Comment: @newacct: Thanks. I hate C for this crap.

Answer (score 0):

If you did it like this:

`typedef char** board_t;`

Then, declare and allocate memory like:

```
int i;
board_t arr = malloc(BOARD_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
for(i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(BOARD_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

For a function defined like:

`void init_board(board_t arr){...}`

Pass on to it like:

`init_board(arr);`

Some points to note:

- If you have used `typedef` for aliasing a pointer type, you cannot have an array-like declaration (where you specify two index sizes) of the newly created type name. You must declare and allocate memory just like you do with pointers.
- In function `init_board` you can treat the parameter `arr` as a 2-D array, and refer to its values like `arr[row][col]`.

Comment: thank you all for the quick answers! is it ok to statically allocate memory? assuming my 2D Array has a constant size:` board_t board [BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];` would be ok? and than pass it to methods as you mentioned.